# So many useless edit suggestions by a user

Tags: support, review-abuse

What do I do when a user is making dozens of useless edit suggestions? It seems like a waste of people's time to have to review each one and reject them one by one... if you catch my drift...

Is there anything built in where once this user gets `n` rejected edits they are no longer able to suggest edits?

I'll admit, some are not *totally useless* but I can't be the only one noticing these things?

Comment: Related http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/271812/213575

Answer (score 12, accepted):

*but I can't be the only one noticing these things* - indeed you're not and the issue was resolved a couple of hours ago (in terms of both editor and some un-attentive reviewers).

Just to note that after a certain amount of rejected edits the system will automatically impose a suggested edit suspension. If it requires further intervention then you should flag one of the edited posts (if not a tag wiki) or flag one of the user's posts (or failing that - one of your own posts) with a custom "other" flag and express your concerns with a couple of links to what's brought it to your attention.

Comment: Thanks - that's the answer I was looking for. Not sure why I didn't think to flag them.

Comment: @d-_-b You could also seek assistance in the [SOCVR](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41570/so-close-vote-reviewers) room if you're unsure what the best action is or simply need more hands on deck.

Answer (score 6):

Ok, [this is bad](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/10667879), and the one that approved it should be banned from review for a while, but the worst is that **the system allows such edits to pass**. AFAIK there's a minimum character limit of 6 non-whitespaces characters to allow an edit to be allowed, and I find no good reason to not being applied here. I don't believe this is actually allowed by design, we may be seeing a bug at work.

Comment: Are tag wiki suggestions different that post suggestions?

Comment: @ryanyuyu yes, the suggestions can only be reviewed by >5kers, and 20kers can edit whatever without peer review.

Comment: I meant in regards to the 6 character restriction.

Comment: @ryanyuyu IMO, if they are not, they should be.

Comment: Usage guidance, like titles, is finicky enough I don't see any good reason to require a minimum character change. It's also very short and completely unformatted, reducing the scope for changes still further.

Comment: @NathanTuggy this is a tag wiki/excerpt! If you won't do something useful for them (which they are in need to), do not edit them, less to remove a whitespace that doesn't bother anyone.

Comment: @Braiam: *This* edit was useless. *Other* five-character edits? Not so much.